# Calling functions in a nested package

Tags: matlab, oop

I'm trying out organising my matlab code into packages, but having to use fully qualified names in nested package functions is killing me.

Say I have a package called +myPack that looks like this:

```
+myPack
    bar.m
    baz.m
```

The bar function might look like

```
function bar()
    myPack.baz()
end
```

This is all fine and logical. However, +myPack is a componant that will be reused in multiple other packages. Lets say one looks like this:

```
+mySuperPack
    foo.m
    +myPack
        bar.m
        baz.m
```

This time, foo calls bar, which in turn calls baz. However, the original code for bar will fail because I have not used the fully qualified name

```
mySuperPack.myPack.baz()
```

Obviously +myPack doesn't know which super pack it is in, so I can't do that.

This also stops you from being able to use static methods in classes that are in packages; the class has to know which package it is in to call its own static methods, which seems crazy.

Is there any way to use nested packages like this, or am I doing packages totally wrong?

Comment: To be honest, I'm thinking its just that I am wrong to include the same subpackage in multiple packages, and should instead have the subpackage in a different folder that is also on the matlab path.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
mySuperPack.myPack.baz()
```

you can write

```
import mySuperPack.myPack.*
baz()
```

You only need to write the import statement once. Unfortunately (and this is one of the few things that really bugs me with MATLAB) `import` only imports into the current workspace, so you need to write it once per function/method.

I *really* wish you could just write it once at the top of a file, and have it import into all functions in the file, or at the top of a class and have it import into all methods of the class, but there you go. At least it's better than always needing fully qualified names everywhere.

PS on the issue of static methods: although you might typically call them as `ClassName.staticMethodName`, or `pkgName.ClassName.staticMethodName`, if you have an object `obj` of that class, you can also call it using `obj.staticMethodName`. Obviously that's not always relevant, but if you're calling a static method from within a normal method it can be convenient, as you don't need to mention (or import) the package.

Comment: Sorry, I think maybe you misunderstand slightly. I'm aware that I can use import, but the issue is that I don't know what to import. The class or package could be contained in any number of super packages so the fully qualified name of the method is not known at runtime. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry - yes, I misunderstood. You added a comment suggesting that a better approach is to not include the same subpackage in multiple packages, but to have it in a separate package. I agree. There's nothing wrong with nested packages, but if you're going to be reusing a package, keep it as a separate package, don't copy it multiple times into different subpackages.

Comment: I wasn't exactly copying the package and pasting it everywhere, but was using SVN to add it as an external, which I now see was unnecessary. Thanks for the confirmation that I was going about it wrong though. If you'd like to add an answer to that effect I'll accept it.